# Receiving "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase'."

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Trying to connect an AngularJS template to firebase, but cannot seem to solve the issue.

I have already npm installed everything I could including typings, angularfire, firebase, and a few more.

Here is my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() {
    const config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBKOJjrzrgT0rXZxonOgk8qM-OIlUjJA4I",
      authDomain: "tn-test-0001.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://tn-test-0001.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "tn-test-0001",
      storageBucket: "tn-test-0001.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "564114143143"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    '''
    "angular-tree-component": "^7.0.2",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "echarts": "^4.0.4",
    "firebase": "^4.3.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
    "isotope-layout": "^3.0.6",
    "mandrill-api": "^1.0.45",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng-scrollreveal": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-echarts": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-isotope": "^0.1.7",
    "ngx-nvd3": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.3.5",
    "ngx-quill": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^6.0.0",
    "rickshaw": "^1.6.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "scrollreveal": "^3.3.6",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.7.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
```

The error I'm recieving in terminal:
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(20,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase'.

I have tried everything I have found on the web thus far and it seems that nothing is working. I'm assuming it is some simple fix, but I cannot find it. Please let me know what other information/code you may need.

Comment: Where did you import the firebase module?

Comment: You didn't import firebase. Also that's Angular7, not AngularJS.

Comment: If you're using the `@angular/fire` (or `angularfire2`) library, you're supposed to add and initialise the Firebase app with `AngularFireModule.initializeApp()` with your Firebase app config passed as the argument. See https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md#5-setup-ngmodule-for-the-angularfiremodule for more info

Comment: Do not post your API keys on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix it you need to add

`import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

**BUT**

You should use `@angular/fire` or (`angularfire2` for older versions)  instead of `firebase` itself.

Then you can define the config in `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: false;
  config = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyBKOJjrzrgT0rXZxonOgk8qM-OIlUjJA4I",
          authDomain: "tn-test-0001.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://tn-test-0001.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "tn-test-0001",
          storageBucket: "tn-test-0001.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "564114143143"
        };
};
```

And then you have to initialize it inside of `AppModule`

```
...
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from './environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.config)
    // Other modules
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This will do the work instead `firebase.initializeApp(config);`. To use other functionality you would also need to use other modules like `AngularFireAuthModule` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was importing firebaseapp

```
import { FirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
```